# problemas al acceder a los valores de un JSON js

Tags: javascript, array, json

estoy intentando mapear los atributo de un JSON, al acceder al id, no me da ningun problema, pero al acceder al atributo name, me devuelve un valor NaN

por algun motivo al introducirse los valores del json en el array pasan a ser tipo number, he intentado parsearlos a string, pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo

este es el codigo:

```js
var hipRetrieved = [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"dick"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"garfield"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"rachel"
    },
    {
        "id":"4",
        "name":"kory"
    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "name":"jason"
    },
]

var arr = [];

for(var i in hipRetrieved) {
    arr.push({
        id: + hipRetrieved[i].id,
        name: + hipRetrieved[i].name
    })
}

console.log(arr);
```

y el resultado

```
[
  { id: 1, name: NaN },
  { id: 2, name: NaN },
  { id: 3, name: NaN },
  { id: 4, name: NaN },
  { id: 5, name: NaN }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sobra el `+` delante del atributo:

```js
var hipRetrieved = [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"dick"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"garfield"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"rachel"
    },
    {
        "id":"4",
        "name":"kory"
    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "name":"jason"
    },
]

var arr = hipRetrieved.map(elem => ({
        id: + elem.id,
        name: elem.name
    })
);


console.log(arr);
```

El operador `+` es similar a hacer un parseFloat: Transforma el string que le sigue a number, si puede. Si no puede, devuelve un NaN (Not a Number).

Te recomiendo usar `for ... of` para recorrer un array antes que `for ... in`